# Twilio client javascript sdk - firefox issue

Tags: javascript, twilio

I can not make the Twilio client work with FireFox browser. I tested with client 1.3 and client 1.4 .

1. The call goes through but I can not listen the called person voice. The called person can hear me.
2. I can hear the DTMF tones with senddigits but the digits are not sent.

My FireFox version is 53.0.3.

Edit:
Included debug messages from console log.

```
WebRTC interfaces with the “moz” prefix (mozRTCPeerConnection, mozRTCSessionDescription, mozRTCIceCandidate)
 have been deprecated.  twilio.min.js:116:384

Device.sounds is deprecated and will be removed in the next breaking release. 
Please use the new functionality available on Device.audio.  twilio.min.js:70:21

Warning: This browser does not support audio output selection.  twilio.min.js:5:393
[Device] Setting up PStream  twilio.min.js:69:375

[WSTransport] Opening socket  twilio.min.js:69:375

[WSTransport] attempting to connect  twilio.min.js:69:375

[WSTransport] Socket opened  twilio.min.js:69:375

[PStream] Setting token and publishing listen  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Device] Stream is ready  twilio.min.js:69:375

onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.  
twilio.min.js:102

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"  twilio.min.js:69:375

The MediaStream passed to createMediaStreamSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence. 
 twilio.min.js:91:322

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"  twilio.min.js:69:375

The MediaStream passed to createMediaStreamSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.  
callme.php

Callback-based pc.getStats is deprecated, and will be removed in the near future! 

Use promise-version! See http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#getstats-example for usage.  twilio.min.js:120

[Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Connection] Disconnecting...  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"  twilio.min.js:69:375
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 274ms]

onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.  twilio.min.js:102

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"  twilio.min.js:69:375
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 210ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 71ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 70ms]

The MediaStream passed to createMediaStreamSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence. 
 twilio.min.js:91:322

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"  twilio.min.js:69:375
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 68ms]
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 71ms]

[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"  twilio.min.js:69:375

OPTIONS XHR https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 70ms]

The MediaStream passed to createMediaStreamSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.  
callme.php

OPTIONS XHR https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 68ms]
GET 
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/sounds/releases/1.0.0/outgoing.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content 0ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 67ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 73ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 73ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointEvents [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 69ms]

Callback-based pc.getStats is deprecated, and will be removed in the near future! Use promise-version! 

See http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#getstats-example for usage.  twilio.min.js:120
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 69ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 77ms]

RTCPeerConnection.getLocalStreams/getRemoteStreams are deprecated. 

Use RTCPeerConnection.getSenders/getReceivers instead.  twilio.min.js:112:259


[Twilio.PeerConnection] Using RTCRtpSender#dtmf  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Connection] Sending digits using RTCDTMFSender  twilio.min.js:69:375
GET 
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/sounds/releases/1.0.0/dtmf-5.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content 0ms]

[Connection] Sending digits using RTCDTMFSender  twilio.min.js:69:375
GET 
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/sounds/releases/1.0.0/dtmf-0.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content 0ms]

[Connection] Sending digits using RTCDTMFSender  twilio.min.js:69:375
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 68ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 78ms]
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 67ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 75ms]
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 67ms]
POST 
XHR 
https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 77ms]

[Connection] Sending digits using RTCDTMFSender  twilio.min.js:69:375
GET 
https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/sounds/releases/1.0.0/dtmf-2.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content 0ms]

[Connection] Disconnecting...  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"  twilio.min.js:69:375

[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"  twilio.min.js:69:375
OPTIONS 
XHR
```

Any help?

Comment: Does it work with a different browser?

Comment: It works with desktop chrome and android chrome.

Comment: Have you checked the functions you are using against their compatibility matrix? Firefox doesn't yet have full support. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js-14

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the Firefox dev tools? Can you try with debug logging turned on (`Twilio.Device.setup(token, { debug: true })`). Can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Included console log in the edit.